# Uniform convergence to an unbounded function

Tags: real-analysis

Is it possible to have a sequence of continuous functions $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ on $[a,b]$ that converges uniformly to a function $f$ but $f$ is not bounded on $[a,b]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a sequence of continuous functions converges uniformly to $f$ then $f$ is continuous and a continuous function in a compact interval $[a,b]$ is always bounded, hence it's not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Uniform limit of continuous functions is necessarily continuous. Also, continuous functions on an interval are necessarily bounded. Combining the two we get that there doesn't exist such a function as required.